# Deletion Using memcpy in an array

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

Given an index and an array of integers, I need to delete the element in the given array which was stored in the given index through the use of `memcpy()`. The new set of elements will be stored on the given array.

Here's an illustration of what I want to do, though I'm having trouble implementing it.

[image]

So `arrayElem` after deleting 10 would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Use `memmove`. It's a "safer" version of memcpy, allowing to work with overlapping memory regions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use [memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy), because source and destination overlap, but you can use [memmove](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove), e.g.:

```
memmove(&a[1], &a[2], 5 * sizeof(a[0]));
```

This copies the 5 elements starting at `a[2]` down to the 5 elements starting at `a[1]`, taking care of the fact that the source and destination regions overlap.

Comment: Sir, but how come my instructor said that it was possible?

Comment: Perhaps your instructor is not as smart as he thinks he is ? Refer him to the man pages for memcpy/memmove (linked above) if he doesn't believe you.

Comment: @newbie well, if he had not imposed a restriction on using a temporary array, this is not impossible using `memcpy()`, IMHO. Check the below answer.

Comment: Sir Paul, how come when I tried using memmove with these values: 10 4 2 3 6 7 1 9  5 8. and deleted at index 1. The resulting values would be: 10 2 3 6 7 1 1 9 5 8. There's a repetition of a number which is 1.

Comment: @newbie: you only moved 5 elements - you would need to have moved 8 elements in this example.

Comment: @Paul Sorry forgot to change it, but the values now also contains duplicates. Here's the current values: 10 2 3 6 7 1 9 5 8 8. Should I post my code?

Comment: @newbie: take some time to understand what `memmove` does, and also look at @Vlad's answer, as he explains why you get duplicate elements at the end of the array. Note that there is no such thing as an "empty" array element - there will always be some value in any unused element(s).

Comment: I got it now and I know why there was a "duplicate". Thanks Sir Paul,  Sir Sourav

Answer (score 2):

You may not use function `memcpy` because the ranges of the array overlap each other. In this case the behaviour will be undefined.

Instead you have to use standard function `memmove`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t remove_by_index( int a[], size_t n, size_t i )
{
    if ( i < n )
    {
        memmove( a + i, a + i + 1, ( n - i - 1 ) * sizeof( *a ) );
        --n;
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 10, 5, 8, 4, 51, 2 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    size_t n = N;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    n = remove_by_index( a, n, 1 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 10 5 8 4 51 2 
1 5 8 4 51 2
```

Comment: The last element is always duplicated... I don't know how you got that output.

Comment: @NorbertBoros Do you see the assignment to n n = remove_by_index( a, n, 1 );?

Comment: Yep, I saw that. In my case that was not necessary. My problem was  const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), instead of doing this I was using my own "counter." See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291982/deleting-element-and-resizing-fixed-size-array-of-structures I am able to remove an element and shift them back with your solution, many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You caanot do this using `memcpy()` **on the same array**. You need to use `memmove()`.

To quote the [`memcpy()` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy)

> The `memcpy()` function copies n bytes from memory area `src` to memory area `dest`. The memory areas must not overlap. Use `memmove(3)` if the memory areas do overlap.

Ref: [`memmove()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove)

However, if you use a temporary array, then, in 2-steps, you can achieve this using `memcpy()`, like

- `memcpy()` the required part of your given array to the temporary array
- `memcpy()` back the temporary array to the given array starting from the required index.

FWIW, neither of the above approach will *clear* the value in index 6. The existing value will be present. You need to do that manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you "must" use `memcpy`, then you can copy 1 byte at a time right on down the array to prevent source and destination overlapping.  In this case, memcpy is standing in for a single memory assignment and is extremely inefficient, but it will do what you want.

```
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    memcpy(arrayElem[i], arrayElem[i+1], sizeof(*arrayElem));
}
```

Icky, but follows the letter of the law laid down in the assignment.  `memmove` though is 100% the correct way to actually do this without the requirement.